# How to handle nested structure when traversing with state monad

Tags: scala, stack-overflow, scalaz, state-monad

I have a nested structures which I'm converting to XML using a scalaz state monad. This works well until I have to deal with multi-level nested structures. Here is a simplified example similar to what I'm doing. Given the following ADT:

```
sealed trait Nested
case object Leaf extends Nested
case class Foo(inner: Nested) extends Nested
case class Bar(inner: Nested) extends Nested
```

I write a converter object using the state monad (assume Scalaz7 and the following imports `import scalaz.{Node => _, _}; import Scalaz._; import scala.xml._`):

```
case class Parents(foos: Int, bars: Int)
type ParentsS[X] = State[Parents, X]

def convertFoo(foo: Foo): ParentsS[Seq[Node]] = for {
  parents <- init[Parents]
  _ <- put[Parents](Parents(parents.foos + 1, parents.bars))
  inner <- convert(foo.inner)
  _ <- put[Parents](parents)
} yield <foo count={ parents.foos.toString }/>.copy(child=inner)

def convertBar(bar: Bar): ParentsS[Seq[Node]] = for {
  parents <- init[Parents]
  _ <- put[Parents](Parents(parents.foos, parents.bars + 1))
  inner <- convert(bar.inner)
  _ <- put[Parents](parents)
} yield <bar count={ parents.bars.toString }/>.copy(child=inner)

def convert(nested: Nested): ParentsS[Seq[Node]] = nested match {
  case Leaf => Seq[Node]().point[ParentsS]
  case foo@Foo(_) => convertFoo(foo)
  case bar@Bar(_) => convertBar(bar)
}

def nested(n: Int): Nested =
  if (n == 0) Leaf
  else {
    if (n % 2 == 0) Bar(nested(n - 1))
    else Foo(nested(n - 1))
  }
```

Depending on my stack settings, `convert(nested(1000)).apply(Parents(0, 0))` will cause a stack overflow in the conversion process. (higher values will cause `nested` to overflow, but this can be ignored since I just created `nested` for this question.):

```
    at scalaz.IdInstances$$anon$1.bind(Id.scala:20)
    at scalaz.StateT$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(StateT.scala:48)
    at scalaz.StateT$$anon$7.apply(StateT.scala:72)
    at scalaz.StateT$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(StateT.scala:48)
    at scalaz.StateT$$anon$7.apply(StateT.scala:72)
    at scalaz.StateT$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(StateT.scala:49)
    at scalaz.StateT$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(StateT.scala:48)
```

My question is - what's the best way to avoid the stack overflow in `scalaz.stateT`? I would like to keep using the state monad as in my real example if makes the XML serialization logic easier to follow and troubleshoot (the actual input structures are JDI mirrored [objects and arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ObjectReference.html) retrieved from live debugging sessions and the inner values are nested fields values).

Edit: to take out the nested stack issue:

```
import util.control.TailCalls
def nested2(n: Int, acc: Nested = Leaf): TailCalls.TailRec[Nested] =
  if (n == 0) TailCalls.done(acc)
  else TailCalls.tailcall(nested2(n - 1, if (n % 2 == 0) Bar(acc) else Foo(acc)))
```

Comment: I am reminded of this thread which I had bookmarked. I just noticed you started it - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaz/QPUs6TWTAm4
I use StateT all the time, but end up with something less elegant when I know I'm going to be traversing more than 200 or so.

Comment: I got the StackOverflow just by running your nested method with n=1000 (without using any Scalaz code).

Comment: @paradigmatic, use the trampolined `nested2` I just added. I suspect the answer to my problem is also to trampoline `convert` but this is not obvious to me how to do it elegantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trampolining can help you avoid the stack overflow here. First for the same setup:

```
sealed trait Nested
case object Leaf extends Nested
case class Foo(inner: Nested) extends Nested
case class Bar(inner: Nested) extends Nested

import scalaz.{Node => _, _}; import Scalaz._;
import scala.util.control.TailCalls, scala.xml._

case class Parents(foos: Int, bars: Int)

def nested(n: Int, acc: Nested = Leaf): TailCalls.TailRec[Nested] =
  if (n == 0) TailCalls.done(acc) else TailCalls.tailcall(
    nested(n - 1, if (n % 2 == 0) Bar(acc) else Foo(acc))
  )
```

Some slightly different type aliases:

```
type TrampolinedState[S, A] = StateT[Free.Trampoline, S, A]
type ParentsS[A] = TrampolinedState[Parents, A]
```

We'll import our `MonadState` instance's methods for the sake of convenience:

```
val monadState = MonadState[TrampolinedState, Parents]
import monadState._
```

And the rest is actually a little more concise, since we don't need the type parameters on `put`, etc.:

```
def convertFoo(foo: Foo): ParentsS[Seq[Node]] = for {
  parents <- init
  _ <- put(Parents(parents.foos + 1, parents.bars))
  inner <- convert(foo.inner)
  _ <- put(parents)
} yield <foo count={ parents.foos.toString }/>.copy(child=inner)

def convertBar(bar: Bar): ParentsS[Seq[Node]] = for {
  parents <- init
  _ <- put(Parents(parents.foos, parents.bars + 1))
  inner <- convert(bar.inner)
  _ <- put(parents)
} yield <bar count={ parents.bars.toString }/>.copy(child=inner)

def convert(nested: Nested): ParentsS[Seq[Node]] = nested match {
  case Leaf => Seq[Node]().point[ParentsS]
  case foo@Foo(_) => convertFoo(foo)
  case bar@Bar(_) => convertBar(bar)
}
```

Now we just run the following (for example):

```
convert(nested(2000).result).apply(Parents(0, 0)).run
```

This works far past the point that the vanilla `State` solution started choking on my machine.

Comment: Thank you! Wish I could +10 this. I used this general approach to prevent SO in a few places where I was previously performing `List[A].traverse[({type λ[α] = State[S, α]})#λ, A]`. It took a little while to figure out how to make this work with Scalaz 6, but I got it eventually.